# Task.ContinueWith callback thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I tried to find an answer for this but couldn't. What I was wondering is that on which thread `Task.ContinueWith` delegate is called.
For await I know that it tries to run it on the captured `SynchronizationContext` but there is nothing documented for `ContinueWith`.

I also tried with a sample program and though it seems it is called on `Threadpool` thread, I suspect that in some scenario it might call on `SynchronizationContext`. Maybe someone can provide a definitive answer.

Comment: see [Task.ContinueWith Method (Action<Task>, CancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions, TaskScheduler)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want the default `await` behavior, pass [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) as a last argument

Comment: @HarshMaurya: Why are you using `ContinueWith` at all? You should almost certainly be using `await` *instead of* `ContinueWith`.

Comment: @StephenCleary That's because I am using C# 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the scheduler that is associated with the continuation. By default, task continuations are scheduled through the [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) scheduler, being the `TaskScheduler` associated with the currently executing task. When `ContinueWith` is not called from within a task, `Current` will return the [`Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) scheduler, which is the default `TaskScheduler` instance provided by the .NET Framework, and which will schedule your tasks on the thread pool.

If you want to influence this behaviour, you can call one of the `ContinueWith` overloads that takes a `TaskScheduler` parameter. A common pattern is to pass `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` when creating continuations on the UI thread, as this would cause the continuation to be dispatched back onto the UI thread when executed.

**Edit**: In reply to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051211/task-continuewith-callback-thread/33051274#comment53923215_33051262): The deadlock may arise if you spawn a child task (intended to run on the thread pool) from a continuation running on the UI thread. In such cases, the child task will inherit the task scheduler from the parent task, which would be bound to the UI thread, causing the child task to run on the UI thread too.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Do background work.
}).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    // Update UI, then spawn child task to do more background work...
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // ...but child task runs on UI thread!
    });
},
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

To resolve this, you can use the `StartNew` overload that accepts a `TaskScheduler` parameter for the child task, and pass `TaskScheduler.Default` to it:

```
    // Update UI, then spawn child task to do more background work...
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // ...and child task now runs on the thread pool.
    },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: I'm using the above code but my solution is not for WPF/WinForms. How do I call the Tasks which have been dispatched to the given TaskScheduler?

Answer (score 2):

`Task.ContinueWith` is scheduled on the `TaskScheduler.Current` unless specified otherwise by the parameters in one of the optional overloads.

If you don't have a custom scheduler in `TaskScheduler.Current` (which is very likely) your continuation will run on the `ThreadPool`.

`Task.ContinueWith` never uses the `SynchronizationContext` unless you create a `TaskScheduler` out of it with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

You can always state explicitly which `TaskScheduler` is needed using one of the available overloads:

```
task.ContinueWith(
    _ => {}, 
    null, 
    CancellationToken.None, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
    TaskScheduler.Default); // Scheduled to the ThreadPool
```

Comment: Is there any scenario that TaskScheduler.Current use SynchronizationContext?
I am having a deadlock in my code which I can easily replicate if I pass TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext as the parameter.
But strangely, it also sometimes happens when I do not pass any parameter, hence the reason for my question

Comment: @HarshMaurya sure, it's possible, but only if you've put it there.

Comment: @HarshMaurya: Do you spawn child tasks from your UI continuation? In that case, you might be affected by an issue that I've described in my updated answer.