# How to correctly use Task.ContinueWith such that it runs on a Thread Pool thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I recently read this blog post: [ContinueWith is Dangerous, Too](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) which states:

> Unfortunately, I see developers making the same mistake with
>   Task.ContinueWith. One of the main problems of StartNew is that it has
>   a confusing default scheduler. This exact same problem also exists in
>   the ContinueWith API. Just like StartNew, ContinueWith will default to
>   TaskScheduler.Current, not TaskScheduler.Default.

I think I have a valid use case for using `ContinueWith` over using await:

```
tasks.Add(database.Table<Table1>().ToListAsync().ContinueWith(sender =>
{
    //some algorithm here
});
tasks.Add(database.Table<Table2>().ToListAsync().ContinueWith(sender =>
{
    //some algorithm here
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now from the above blog post I presume the correct way to use this is:

```
tasks.Add(database.Table<Table1>().ToListAsync().ContinueWith(sender =>
{
    //some algorithm here
}, TaskScheduler.Default);
tasks.Add(database.Table<Table2>().ToListAsync().ContinueWith(sender =>
{
    //some algorithm here
}, TaskScheduler.Default);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Is this correct?

Does the above code mean that the `ContinueWith` will now run on a ThreadPool thread?

Whats the difference between **TaskScheduler.Current, TaskScheduler.Default** and **TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronisationContext()**

Comment: "I think I have a valid use case for using ContinueWith over using await" No, you don't.  You should be using `await` to add continuations here, just like you basically always should be.  You will almost certainly implement the continuation incorrectly doing this, and the amount of work it would take to do it correctly will be *much* more than simply using `await`.

Comment: @Servy if I use `await` as you suggest then both tasks will run synchronously. I would like both tasks in parralel. I think that means your suggestion of using await wouldnt work. Please correct me if I'm wrong, my knowledge of task based programming isnt great

Comment: You make an `async ` method, await the query, do whatever other work you have, and then call that method.  That's basically the response to basically any situation you think you need to use `ContinueWith`.

Comment: For asynchronous concurrency, save the tasks into variables and then use `await Task.WhenAll`. If you need to run CPU-bound code on a different thread, use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct, you can find the confirmation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8).

Specifying that you want to use the default task scheduler, it will be using the ThreadPool.

> The default task scheduler is based on the .NET Framework 4 thread pool, which provides work-stealing for load-balancing, thread injection/retirement for maximum throughput, and overall good performance. It should be sufficient for most scenarios.

As pointed by *d.moncada* there is a similar question with a very good anwer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051211/task-continuewith-callback-thread)